# Have I organised my django app correctly?

Tags: python, django, structure, package

I'm in a situation where I need to merge two Django apps into a single, re-usable app. Neither are particularly large, but they are certainly not trivial apps and to preserve readability / sanity I'm trying to  keep the two apps separated to some extent.

I could set up each app as a sub-package (which would be a pythonic way to achieve this end), or I can stick to Django's conventions and split the functionality separately in each case.

A Pythonic 'sub-package' approach:

```
package
|-- __init__.py
|-- views.py
|-- models.py     # imports models from both sub-packages
|-- tests.py      # imports TestCase instances from both sub-packages
|-- etc.          # shared stuff
|-- a
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- views.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- etc.      # a-specific code
`-- b
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- views.py
    |-- models.py
    |-- tests.py
    `-- etc.      # b-specific code
```

Or to appease the Django gods more directly:

```
package
|-- __init__.py
|-- views
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- a.py
|   `-- b.py
|-- models
|   |-- __init__.py  # imports models from a and b
|   |-- a.py
|   `-- b.py
|-- tests
|   |-- __init__.py  # imports TestCase instances from a and b
|   |-- a.py
|   `-- b.py
`-- etc. # shared/additional files
```

While I'd lean towards the former at the moment (which feels a little lighter), my gut tells me that although both work (and both involve importing 'hacks' to conform to Django's structure) the best choice depends on the contents of a and b - specifically how much of the code is shared or app-specific. It doesn't feel right to be constantly repeating the __ init__.py, a.py, b.py pattern in every subdirectory!

I'm interested in knowing which would is more appropriate from people with more experience dealing with Python!

*ps.
I'm aware they could live as two distinct apps, but they are so inter-dependant now that I do feel like they should be merged! (even aside from the improved portability of a single Django app)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flat is better than nested.

A "composite" application, built from two peer applications is fine.  It works well.

And it promotes reuse by allowing the two components to be "plug-and-play" options in the larger application.

Don't nest things unless you're forced to.  The number one reason *forcing* you to nest is name collisions. You don't have that so you don't really need any nesting.

Comment: For readability of the answer to the layman, could you make it clear which one is 'flat' and which one is 'nested' and which one is thus better?

Comment: Afaik the zen is referring to python code, rather than file structure, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in python but I always like to seperate applications and other artifact out as much as I can.

I am following the approach that is described in this [blog](http://blog.apps.chicagotribune.com/2010/03/08/advanced-django-project-layout/) for my own django project and it requires a little bit of tweaking on django. It has served me well so far.

The direct link to the [github project](http://github.com/ryanmark/django-project-templates)

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I often want to organize views and tests somehow, so I use structure like this:

```
package
|-- __init__.py
|-- models.py     # models are in one file
|-- etc.          # shared stuff
|-- tests
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- tests_orders.py
|   |-- tests_clients.py
|   |-- 
|   `-- etc.
|-- views
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- orders.py
|   |-- clients.py
|   |-- 
|   `-- etc.
```

For bigger projects having view functions in one file is a pain (for me).

This is what works for some projects I am working on - hopefully someone find this useful also.